# How to debug an ssh terminal session?

Tags: ssh, debian

I'm having an issue with a block of machines running debian 6 (ARM). When I ssh to them I'm only able to get about 3 lines of output from any command (eg 'ps -ax') before the session is locked up and must be killed.

Running 'ssh -vvv' doesn't show any errors.

EDIT: I can get single commands to execute: `ssh root@server "ps -ax"`. If I login and try the same command the lock-up occurs.

What else should I try to see what's going on?

Comment: Do you know the specs of the servers? ie, are they low end VPSes with 128mb of RAM or so and you're trying to run a RAM intensive service?

Comment: servers are fanless ARM based machines. Small footprint. 1g of RAM. Not much else running.

Comment: Is it possible to pipe the output to a text file (yeah, you'll lose the session) but then look at the text file the next time you log it?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound  like an ssh error, it sounds like a networking error, specifically an issue with the MTU settings.  Try setting up MTU clamping or ensuring the MTU on both the client and server is less then the maximum MTU across the path.

Comment: I wondered about MTU size so I tried this: `ping -c 1 -s $((5000-28)) -M do machine-ip` - came back and told me `mtu=1500` which is what's set on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ssh -v [target] at initial connection.

Comment: Tried this: got lots of info until the lock-up. Then silence. Waited 20-30 minutes with nothing further.

Comment: Is there a log on the server end?

Comment: Can't really get to it.